# NavigationLinks stay highlighted when using both `.background` and `VStack`

Tags: swiftui

The navigation link in the following code stays highlighted even when the navigation is popped.

Comment out one of the two and it works as expected.

Tested with iOS 14 beta 6 and Xcode 12 beta 6

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("B")) {
                        Text("A")
                    }
                }
                Text("Bottom")                   // <- this 
            }
            .background(Text("Hi"))             // <- and this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. File a bug to feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

This happen also to me when text is on top, weird

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           VStack {
               Text("Top") // <- this
               List {
                   NavigationLink(destination: Text("B")) {
                       Text("A")
                   }
               }
                              
           } 
       }
    }
}
```